Spring Authorization Server threw exception with message: DelegatingAuthenticationConverter
I am confused at what is causing this error, I first started noticing this when I migrated from version 1.2 to 1.4 of the spring oauth2 authorization server. Below you will find relevant files to help debug the issue.
Error output when trying to run ./gradlw bootRun. It fails to build
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/something/auth_service/configuration/OAuth2SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain' threw exception with message: org/springframework/security/web/authentication/DelegatingAuthenticationConverter   
    

When I tried using the spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server it used an older dependency spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:1.2.1 instead of 1.4.1. Not sure why that was happening but just decided to explicitly specify the dependencies.
Build.Gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'application'

}

group = 'com.something'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

application {
    mainClass = 'com.something.auth_service.AuthApplication'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    all {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


bootRun {
    args = ["--spring.profiles.active=dev"]
}

bootTestRun {
    args = ["--spring.profiles.active=dev"]
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.18.0'

    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:ses:2.28.20'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.28.20'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:auth:2.28.20'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.28.20'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:regions:2.28.20'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.28.20'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:services:2.28.20'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core:2.28.20'
    implementation 'jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api:2.1.3'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:sesv2:2.28.20'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:auth:2.28.20'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:3.4.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.4.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'redis.clients:jedis:5.1.2'

    implementation 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.0'
    implementation 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.2'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.12.3'

    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:1.4.1'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.12.3'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.12.3'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    implementation 'jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:2.1.1'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}



This is my Spring Authorization Server configuration, which includes login settings. I successfully got the login routes working and tested the client registration. However, everything started breaking after upgrading to the latest version of Spring Authorization Server.
OAuth2 Security Config

package com.something.auth_service.configuration;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;

import com.something.auth_service.configuration.user.CustomUserDetailsService;
import com.something.auth_service.configuration.user.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider;
import com.something.auth_service.repository.UserRepository;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.security.KeyPair;

@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Configuration
public class OAuth2SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService(userRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder customPasswordEncoder() {
        String idForEncode = "bcrypt";
        Map<String,PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
        encoders.put(idForEncode, new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("bcrypt", encoders);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
        CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder sharedPasswordEncoder) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider(userDetailsService, sharedPasswordEncoder);
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository,
            AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer =
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.authorizationServer();

        // Failed below here.
        http
        .securityMatcher(authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher())
        .with(authorizationServerConfigurer, (authorizationServer) ->
            authorizationServer
                .oidc((oidc) ->
                    oidc.clientRegistrationEndpoint((clientRegistrationEndpoint) -> oidc.clientRegistrationEndpoint(Customizer.withDefaults())  
                    )
                )
        )
        .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
            authorize
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/create-account").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/oauth2/authorize").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .formLogin(formLogin -> {
                    formLogin.loginPage("/login");
                    formLogin.usernameParameter("emailOrUsername"); 
                    formLogin.passwordParameter("password");
                    formLogin.successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                        System.out.println("Login Succeeded.");
                        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                        response.getWriter().write("Login successful!");
                        response.getWriter().flush();
                    });
                    
                })
                .logout(logout -> {
                    logout.logoutUrl("http://localhost:8082/logout");
                    logout.logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8082/login");
                    logout.invalidateHttpSession(true);
                    logout.clearAuthentication(true);
                    logout.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
                    logout.logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                        System.out.println("Logout Succeeded.");
                        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                        response.getWriter().write("Logout successful for "+request.getSession().getId());
                        response.getWriter().flush();
                    });
                })
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
        .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> {        
            exceptions.accessDeniedHandler((request, response, accessDeniedException) -> {
                request.getSession().invalidate();
                System.out.println("Login Failed, Access Denied.");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK); 
                response.getWriter().write("Login Failed, Access Denied.");
                response.getWriter().flush();
            });
            exceptions.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("http://localhost:8082"),
                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                );
            }
            );
        
        return http.build();
    }

    
    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }

    
}



It seems like you're mixing Spring Boot 3.2.0 and 3.4.1. When I implemented a Spring Boot Auth-server a couple of months ago, I followed one of the samples below https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server  That involved org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server instead of spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server. BR

That would make a lot of sense, let me migrate my spring and I will get back to you on that :). I didn't even notice I was using an older spring plugin.

After bumping Spring Boot plugin, you may let deps follow versions in plugin by removing :3.4.1

@RoarS. Can you make this the acceptable answer so I can upvote it?

Thanks, did I include all highlights that fixed the issue in the below answer?

Yes you included everything I needed. Just a stupid mistake on my part, not noticing the version difference lol.

It seems like you're mixing Spring Boot 3.2.0 and 3.4.1. After bumping Spring Boot plugin to 3.4.1, you may let deps follow versions in plugin by removing :3.4.1.
You might consider using org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server instead of spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server.
